# Coded UI thinks control is in a different position

Tags: c#, winforms, coded-ui-tests

I haven't been able to find someone else who has this same issue and it is extremely frustrating. Basically, for whatever reason, Coded UI is seeing a control in a different area then where it actually is. Like this:
[Bounding Rectangle for Label with "IDLE" in it is up and to the left of the control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcRk1.png)

As you can see in the picture for some reason the Bounding Rectangle is up and to the left of the selected Label with the word "IDLE" in it. This is the first time I have seen this issue and after doing like 50 googles searches I decided to come here.

First off I am using Coded UI with a Windows Forms Application (I don't know if that makes a difference), it seems to do the same thing with all Windows Forms Applications, it has worked fine for all my WPF applications.

Second, no matter how many times I record my click on a button in my application or something of the sort, running the recorded method will always click off the button (due to it thinking the button is positioned up and to the left of the control). Up and to the left seems to be the only consistent thing, how much up and to the left varies based off of where the application is on the screen.

If anyone has any ideas or something I can try please help, I have no idea what is going on. If you need anymore information feel free to ask.
Thanks

Edit for Code sample:

```
public class Controller : WinWindow
{
#region Constructors
    public Controller()
    {
        SearchProperties[PropertyNames.Name] = "My Sample C#";
        SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression(PropertyNames.ClassName, "WindowsForms10.Window", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
        WindowTitles.Add("My Sample C#");

        enableWindow = new EnableWindow(this);
    }
    #endregion


    public WinEdit CommunicationSetup
    {
        get
        {
            if(communicationSetup == null)
            {
                communicationSetup = new WinEdit(this);
                communicationSetup.SearchProperties[PropertyNames.ControlName] = "Communication";
                communicationSetup.WindowTitles.Add("My Sample C#");
            }
            return communicationSetup;
        }
    }
    private WinEdit communicationSetup;

 }
```

Extra Edit:
To Click on the thing I've used this:

```
Mouse.Click(new Point(obj.BoundingRectangle.Location.X + 20, obj.BoundingRectangle.Location.Y + 10));
```

and This:

```
Mouse.Click(obj);
```

Both click up and to the left of the control, as expected since the BoundingRectangle show there as seen in the picture

Edit: To replace "right" with "left" because I'm clearly an idiot and don't know my directions lol

Edit: Here is some more pictures showing the DrawHighlight() for the button Enable on my application, sorry I have to take a ton of information out for company policy reasons which might make it a little difficult to see what everything is going on but I have to

I also moved the application around so you can see how much of a difference DrawHighlight() has when the application is moved

[Application dragged further down and to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtMHc.png)

Comment: Can you show some code that you tried?

Comment: I edited for a sample code, I don't think it should matter what the code is though, it can find the Control just fine. Its just knowing where exactly it is on the screen that seems to be the issue

Comment: Not familiar with `Coded-UI`, but my guess is `BoundingRectangle` is in client coordinates, meaning the rectangle returned is relative to the control's immediate parent. The rectangle needs to be translated to screen coordinates, typically using `control.RectangleToScreen(...)`

Comment: That was a good thought @Loathing, I tried it and that doesn't seem to be the problem, still the same case but thanks for the idea, it gave me some ideas

Comment: @DLTruman Does the button have a normal parent hierarchy? One thought is mixing `winforms` and `WPF`, or using `pinvoke` `SetParent(...)` could result in a case where the button needs a more advanced approach to translate its bounding box. You should try to `pinvoke` `GetWindowRect(button.Handle, ref RECT rect);` and compare the results.

Comment: Also, probably a good idea to verify whatever criteria is used to locate the control (looks like `"Communication"`) is unique.

Comment: @Loathing, thanks for your comments it helped me get to an answer, atleast for now. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a consistent way to solve my problem, thanks to @Loathing for his comments on my question. Here is how I solved it:

```
var ret=new Rectangle();
GetWindowRect(obj.WindowHandle, ref ret);
Mouse.Hover(new Point(ret.X, ret.Y));
```

I still am not sure why this works so if someone sees this and understands feel free to comment and explain, I'm a little fuzzy on what goes on with GetWindowRect.

Comment: Be aware that `System.Drawing.Rectangle != RECT`. `Rectangle` uses `width` and `height` fields, but `RECT` uses `right` and `bottom`. The first two fields (x, y) and (Left, Top) will match, but not the last two fields.

Comment: Most controls on the screen you can see have a corresponding `Handle` that the operating system uses to track the properties (e.g. position, size, events). You can use the `pinvoke` methods, such as `GetWindowRect` to get information on those properties, and the identifier is the `Handle`.

Comment: @DLTruman Can you provide more details? or example? I am having basically the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

what is stored in the `obj` variable that you try to pass to `Click()` method?

The problem might occur because you have not enough unique properties, who may definitely describe the control. Try to add additional `SearchProperties`. The most valuable would be a `Control ID` or `Automation ID`. If you cannot obtain this property on the wanted control, ask your development team to add it.

Try also to debug the method. Investigate of is returned in `BoundingRectangle` property of the control. Try out `DrawHighlight()` method. It will mark the position of the control with a blue rectangle. Another option would be to use `TryGetClickablePoint()` method. Maybe your control's size is bigger than you can visually obtain. The last but not least: examine your control from `UIMap Editor` and its whole hierarchy. You might find that the control you are looking for was badly recorded.

If nothing helps, then provide some more information and results of your investigation.

Good luck with that one.

Alex

Comment: obj in this case is a UITestControl, so for a button in this application it is just a WinButton object. the correct SearchProperties are used with the correct Automation ID, the picture I took in the original post uses DrawHighlight() to get the blue highlight. Maybe you can elaborate on how TryGetClickablePoint() would help me? It attempts the click, it just attempts the click within the highlight box that is shown in the picture because from my understanding that is where Coded UI things the button is.

Comment: continued: I've attempted this on several Windows Forms Applications now and they all do the same thing, I have also done it on different environments, using VS12 and VS13 as well as working in Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. Is it just a problem with Windows Forms Applications? That wouldn't make sense because from what I found it should be fine but since in my experience it works fine with WPF but not Windows Forms I just don't know where to go from here..

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across some interesting results when trying to debug cross browser tests between IE and chrome that similarly mimicked what you've reported. It turns out that CodedUI and IE seems to be sensitive to the display scaling. I was using a multi monitor setup with different resolutions and changing each's scaling, using mostly 125%. The control's top and left coordinates were always off in IE and I could never figure out why. After doing some math and dividing by 125%, sure enough the number matched the coordinates it was supposed to be reporting. If I tried to change the monitor scaling without restarting windows, the issue got worse and I would also miss clicks. I imagine your solution to GetWindowRect appears be DPI sensitive as well, and reporting the correct coordinates with scaling taken into account.

Link to microsoft page that loosely discusses this:
[Understanding Screen Scaling Issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671605(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I get this all the time and the only way I managed to resolve it is restarting windows (go figure yet another MS solutions with Restart of the entire OS). Anyhow, in my case, it could be working fine, but later I would RD into my desktop from a laptop and everything would go nuts with this issue. I had to restart when working directly with PC and restart again when working from RD session.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue fairly frequently as well.  In my case whenever my code tried to download a file, the browser would popup the little download bar at the bottom.  From then on, all my location rectangles would be off by the height of that bar.

My guess is that it is a bug in Microsoft's CodedUI that is unable to reset itself when the window it is testing changes sizes in certain cases.  I have found a lot of bugs in CodedUI, I really hope that some day they get it more stable.

The fix for my issues so far has been to close the Internet Explorer window I was using to run the tests and restart it.  CodedUI can't even get this right though, so I go out and kill all iexplorer.exe processes then re-start the browser.